# buy any one specific product A or B and get C free. If A or B is removed C product will not be free with other products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to do some customisation in the `woocommerce cart`.

Suppose someone buys anyone product "A" or "B" then "C" will automatically be given free.

1. Product"A" with "C" product free (if the customer add product "C" then it will be free )
   or
2. Product "B" with "C" product free (if the customer add product "C" then it will be free )
   if
3. if any of these products "A" or "B" are not in the cart then the "C" product will not be free with any other products.

I am trying this coding but all goes wrong
if anyone helps me I will be very grateful to you. thank you

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'add_free_if_id_in_cart' );

function add_free_if_id_in_cart() {
    if( is_admin() ) return;
    if( WC()->cart->is_empty() ) return;

    $product_bought_ids = array(395,394);
    $product_free_id = 411;

    $product_bought_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_bought_id );
    $product_bought_in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_bought_cart_id );

    $product_free_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_free_id );
    $product_free_in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_free_cart_id );
    
    if( !$product_bought_in_cart ) {
        if( $product_free_in_cart ) WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $product_free_in_cart );
    } else {
        if( !$product_free_in_cart ) WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_free_id );
    }
}
```

Comment: where is `$product_bought_id` defined? Is that supposed to be `$product_bought_ids`?

Comment: I used this code as per your correction. but when I add product id "411" it is showing " has been added to your cart." but not showing in the product cart list.